# Excel VBA count how many of a range are part of a text

Tags: excel, vba

I'm struggling with a problem I thought would be easy to solve. Unfortunately I wasn't able to. I have a cell containing a text, actually an series of codes divided by ";". Furthermore I have a range of cells containing single codes. Now I want to count how many of the single codes are in the text.

```
    Text-Cell:  AA01;AA05;AB03;AB05;CD07

    Range:
          AA01
          AB05
          AB07
          CD07
          CD09


    Result: 3
```

The range is dynamic, so the number of cells I'm looking at do differ. I'm looking for a code like:

```
    Function NumberContaining(RANGE As Variable, TEXT as Variable) as  Integer

    Dim RESULT as Integer
    Dim CELL as Variable
    RESULT=0

    For(CELL in RANGE)
         RESULT=RESULT+WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Text,”=*” & CELL & “*”)

    Next


    NumberContaining=RESULT

    End Function
```

Unfortunately I couldn't make it work. I would be glad if your could help me. Thanks.

Comment: You could use an array formula for this `=SUM(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A3:A7,A1))))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the separator for your strings is always going to be the same (`;`) you can use the [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) function then loop through the array to see if any of the variants match any of the cells in your range.

Try this instead:

```
Function NumberContaining(rng As Range, txt As String) As Integer

Dim sArray() As String
Dim element As Variant

sArray = Split(txt, ";")

For Each element In sArray
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, Trim(element)) > 0 Then NumberContaining = NumberContaining + 1
Next element

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately there are also some empty spaces, which are wildly distributed. By deleting all empty spaces your approached worked too.

Comment: No problem, if that's the case you could also use `If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, Trim(element)) > 0 Then...`

Comment: Hey thanks, this does even a better job. By this way the empty cells won't get counted :)

Answer (score 0):

Using your template... (you had some issues with your syntax). However, use Jordan's approach as this would flag e.g. AA01 as a match for AA011.

```
Function NumberContaining(rRANGE As RANGE, vTEXT As Variant) As Integer

Dim RESULT As Integer
Dim CELL As RANGE

For Each CELL In rRANGE
    RESULT = RESULT + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(vTEXT, "=*" & CELL & "*")
Next

NumberContaining = RESULT

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved my problem.
I'm new to VBA, only had R, Python and Matlab so far, so the syntax is really strange for me.